# Remove Object from Dictionary declare in AppDelegate Class when remove object from local array

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
localArray = [[APPDELEGATE dicGlobalCat] valueForKey:@"array"];   

//ViewDidload
// get array list from appdelegate Dictionary to local array

-(void)btnCloseCategory:(UIButton *) button
{        
    int index = (int)button.tag;

    [localArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];    
//here i'm remove object only from local array.

    [tbl reloadData];
}
```

//remove object only from local array, it also remove object from appdelegate Dictionary. how it possiable?

Comment: That code is clearly Objective-C and not Swift, so why use the swift tag?

Comment: @DávidPásztor by mistake tag swift, it's objective -c, Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

When you write `localArray = [[APPDELEGATE dicGlobalCat] valueForKey:@"array"]`, `localArray` points to address of `[[APPDELEGATE dicGlobalCat] valueForKey:@"array"]`.

*It means that they point to same object*

So when you remove object from an array, both of them are affected.

## Solution

To resolve this issue, create a copy of `[[APPDELEGATE dicGlobalCat] valueForKey:@"array"]` before assign it to `loadArray`.

```
localArray = [[[APPDELEGATE dicGlobalCat] valueForKey:@"array"] mutableCopy];
```